# using css selectors in styled components

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

I recently moved to `styled components` as my styling method. I'm facing an issue on how to use `selectors` in styled components. For example i have a css like this

```
.input-w-l-container{
    // padding:10px;
    border:1px solid;
    height:42px;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.32);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-radius: 4px;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  .input-w-l-container>label{
    position:absolute;
    top:-11px;
    // left:25px;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    letter-spacing: 0.4px;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);

  }

  .input-w-l-container>input{
    border:none;
    height:32px;
    margin-top: -5px;
    outline: none;
    padding-left: 4px;
  }
```

How to use this css using style components. My current approach is something like the below code. But obviously it does not work

```
const InputContainer = styled.div`
    border:1px solid;
    height:42px;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.32);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-radius: 4px;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column-reverse;
    font-size: 12px !important;

    & > label {
        position:absolute;
        top:-11px;
        font-size: 12px;
        padding-left: 5px;
        padding-right: 10px;
        letter-spacing: 0.4px;
        color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    }

    & > input {
        border:none;
        height:32px;
        margin-top: -5px;
        outline: none;
        padding-left: 4px;
    }

`;
```

Comment: You have to individually style the children. This article should help you: https://styled-components.com/docs/basics#how-do-styled-components-work-within-a-component

Comment: I refered this document. But could not fully understand. Can you give me a example?

Answer (score 1):

the styled components add inline styles to the element. so you can add there only the styles that you can add on this component inline.

what you can do is create a few styles, like this:

```
const InputContainer = styled.div`
border:1px solid;
height:42px;
border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.32);
box-sizing: border-box;
border-radius: 4px;
overflow: hidden;
display: flex;
flex-flow: column-reverse;
font-size: 12px !important;
`
const Label = styled.label`
    position:absolute;
    top:-11px;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    letter-spacing: 0.4px;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
`;
const Input = styled.input`
    border:none;
    height:32px;
    margin-top: -5px;
    outline: none;
    padding-left: 4px;
`;
```

then replace the `label` and `input` element with `Label` and `Input` accordingly.
for example instead this:

```
<InputContainer>
   <label>name</label><input type="text" placeholder="Jhon Doe"/>
</InputContainer>
```

type this>

```
<InputContainer>
   <Label>name</Label><Input type="text" placeholder="Jhon Doe"/>
</InputContainer>
```